# Group member cannot write even with write permission

Tags: files, permissions, group

The logged in user is a member of a group that has a write permission on a folder. But when this user is trying to write something, "permission is denied".

The log below summarizes the question:

```
subv:/www/tracer/ whoami
frank
subv:/www/tracer/
subv:/www/tracer/ ls -ltr 
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 root tracer 4096 Jan 20 12:25 convert.tracer.com
subv:/www/tracer/ groups frank
frank : frank tracer
subv:/www/tracer/ > convert.tracer.com/test
-bash: convert.tracer.com/test: Permission denied
subv:/www/tracer/
```

Output of "ls -bail /www/tracer/convert.tracer.com/":

```
subv:~/ ls -bail /www/tracer/convert.tracer.com/
total 8
38010883 drwxrwxr-x 2 root tracer 4096 Jan 20 12:25 .
38010882 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Jan 20 12:25 ..
subv:~/
```

Comment: The parent directories needs the permissions as well.

Comment: does `test` file already exist? what are its permissions if so?

Comment: Do you have SELinux activated? Can you also do an "ls -bail convert.tracer.no/"

Comment: @hesse you mean, the group owner of "/www" and "/www/tracer" should be tracer?

Comment: @Nikhil no, there is nothing in "/www/tracer/convert.tracer.com/". Its an empty dir.

Comment: @tmow updated the question with the outpu.

Comment: @frankmoss thanks I've updated the answer also

Comment: To **create** a new file in a dir, you (user or groupmember) needs `+w` permissions on that dir. To **write** to an existing file in that dir, you only need `+w` permissions on that file. In both cases you will need the `+x` permission on the directory.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Group membership is re-read on login. `groups` seem to report the groups you are in according to `/etc/group` and does not reflect membership of groups in the current session.

Use the command `id -Gn` to show the groups that you are currently an active member of. Solution: relogin to apply the group changes.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 18.04 system I actually needed to do a full reboot via `sudo reboot`, not sure if that's expected?

Comment: @ComputerScientist You have to relogin for group changes to apply, or use the `newgrp $group_name` command to obtain the group membership if allowed. Rebooting also works, but is a bit drastic.

Answer (score 0):

What about the permissions of the directory where you have the file?

Are you able to edit the file, i.e. with vim, and save it?

Try to do something like

```
chmod g+w .
```

#### UPDATE

```
subv:~/ ls -bail /www/tracer/convert.tracer.com/
total 8
38010883 drwxrwxr-x 2 root tracer 4096 Jan 20 12:25 .
38010882 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Jan 20 12:25 ..
```

It could there was an issue while creating the tracer directory, I see strange spaces between root and 4096 in the second line of your output.

I would try this as root:

```
cd /www/tracer/
chown root:root .
chown root:tracer convert.tracer.com
```

If it's still ok, I'd check the group name in /etc/group, doing a

```
cat -v /etc/group
```

Checking that there are not non printable chars in root and tracer group

Finally if you still have the issue could be SELinux or an issue with the file system.

Comment: ask questions in comments, not answers. He shows the permissions of the directory. If the shell cant write to it, neither can vim. The directory already has `g+w` perms.

Comment: @Patrick yes, you are right... But if he cannot write on the file through a directory (convert.tracer.com/test) I was thinking the issue is the directory... I didn't see well in the log provided.