# Why can't I create a file in a directory where I have group write access?

Tags: permissions, group

There's a situation I don't quite understand.
I have this directory, where the group 'webadmin' has `rwx` rights :

```
$ ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 root webadmin 4096 Aug 27 12:17 .
     ⋮                                       ⋮
```

I am in the group webadmin :

```
$ groups eino
eino : eino sudo webadmin
```

however, I can't create any file in the directory :

```
$ touch test.txt
touch: cannot touch 'test.txt': Permission denied
```

How come? Shouldn't the `rwx` permissions give me right to do it?

Comment: refer to this [post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29545/group-member-cannot-write-even-with-write-permission)

Comment: Yes indeed, as Lekensteyn's response showed, the group addition is not applied during the current session. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Log out and log back in. You probably added the group during your current session.