# "permission denied" when appending with echo, but working with vi

Tags: shell-script, files, permissions

I have a file

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root mygroup 0 Sep 10 14:54 /etc/nginx/mygroup.txt
```

The access rights are set so that the group `mygroup` has read and write permissions for the file. Writing the file with a member of `mygroup` works when editing with `vi /etc/nginx/mygroup.txt`. However, when I try to append a text to the file with the same user using

```
echo "blaa" >> /etc/nginx/mygroup.txt
```

I get

```
-sh: 3: cannot create /etc/nginx/mygroup.txt: Permission denied
```

The directory permission for the containing directory are

```
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root    4096 Sep 10 16:07 nginx
```

The user is able to list the contents of the directory.

Why does this happen and how can I add a line to the text file from bash without using a text editor?

Additional information based on comments:

The user has no sudo rights.

Is this a duplicate of [Why can't sudo redirect stdout to /etc/file, but sudo 'nano' or 'cp' can?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19707/why-cant-sudo-redirect-stdout-to-etc-file-but-sudo-nano-or-cp-can) ? I don't think so, because running

```
printf "blaa" | tee /etc/nginx/
```

produces also

```
tee: /etc/nginx/whitelist-jutik.txt: Permission denied
```

Also all the other suggested duplicate questions are for users with sudo rights, so I think this question is not a duplicate of any of them.

**Edit:** finding this question solved the problem: [Group member cannot write even with write permission](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29545/group-member-cannot-write-even-with-write-permission)

Apparently the group permissions were not completely in effect. Logging in again with the user solved the problem, he can write the file with both vi and echo.

Comment: What are the directory permissions?

Comment: I edited the answer to display directory permissions.

Comment: You should also edit the question to demonstrate that this is not https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19707/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42801/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/ , or  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31322/ yet again.  (-:

Comment: "_doing it with `vi`_". Do you use `vi /etc/nginx/mygroup.txt` or `sudo vi /etc/nginx/mygroup.txt`?

Comment: The user has no sudo rights, so I use vi without sudo.

Comment: Why would the error say "create"? Doesn't the file exist yet?

Comment: Well, that's what I'm curious about too.

Comment: When you were using `vi`, did the file already exist? Similarly: when you were using `echo` did the file already exist? Your user doesn't have permission to _create_ a file in that directory but it does have permission to _modify_ the existing file as shown to us.

Comment: The file existed as a 0-byte file (created a bit earlier with touch).

Comment: In both cases? Or just for `vi`? Or just for `echo`?

Comment: Hard to say. I recreated the file and all the permissions, but cannot reproduce the vi part anymore. :/

Comment: Ok, found the solution and edited question accordingly (see last part). Thanks everyone.

Comment: Simon, please write an answer summarising your findings rather than updating the question. You can then accept it (tick-mark alongside the voting buttons on the left) so we can (easily) see the question's been answered.